# Handling large datasets in dimple.js to render a chart

Tags: javascript, optimization, d3.js, charts, dimple.js

I wish to draw charts for large datasets using dimple.js. My code works absolutely fine. But the only problem is that the chart takes more than 45 seconds to come up. I am looking for some kind of an optimization in my code to reduce the time taken for the rendering of the chart. The following is the code for my area chart:

```
var dataset = [];

// The arrays xpoints and ypoints are populated dynamically 
// with hundreds of thousands of points

var xpoints = chartData["xdata"];
var ypoints = chartData["ydata"];
var area1;

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#" + mychart, 700, 600);
var x, y;

for (var i = 0; i < xpoints.length; i++)
    dataset.push({
        x : xpoints[i],
        y1 : parseFloat(ypoints[i])
    });

var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, dataset);
myChart.setBounds(75, 30, 480, 330);

y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "y1");

x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "x");
area1 = myChart.addSeries("First", dimple.plot.area, [ x, y ]);

var l = myChart.addLegend(65, 10, 510, 20, "right");        
myChart.draw(1500);
```

Is there some way to optimize this code in either dimple.js itself or maybe using d3.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid Dimple is not very performant for hundreds of thousands of points.  It's drawing logic is built for flexibility and for cases like this you need to write specific d3 code (think of Dimple as a Swiss-Army Knife but here you need a scalpel). Even with raw d3 you might run into problems with a path containing that number of points.  Certainly try raw d3 but you might need to write some more complex additional logic to average every n points together and then fill in detail on zoom.  Also remember that even with perfect client code you will suffer a noticeable wait simply getting that volume of data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!!. I was adamant on using dimple.js itself and not raw d3.

What I did was I aggregated the values first and then passed them to the `chart.draw()` function

The time taken to render the graph now is reduced from 40 seconds to 12 seconds, which is much better.

For now, my aggregation function just sums up the values for a particular category. Maybe the implementation in the draw() function is a little more complex and is therefore taking extra time. `xpoints[]` and `ypoints[]` are my arrays with lakhs of points.

Earlier, I just did this:

```
dataset.push({
                x : xpoints[i],
                y1 : parseFloat(ypoints[i])

                });
```

Now, I first apply an aggregation as follows:

```
                var isPresent = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < unique_x.length; j++) {
                    if (xpoints[i] == unique_x[j]) {
                        y_val = parseFloat(ypoints[i]);
                        if (isNaN(y_val)) {
                            y_val = 0;
                        }
                        y_sum[j] = y_sum[j] + y_val;
                        isPresent = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPresent == false) {
                    unique_x.push(xpoints[i]);
                    y_sum.push(parseFloat(ypoints[i]));
                }
```

Then, I do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < unique_x.length; i++) {
                dataset.push({
                    x : unique_x[i],
                    y1 : y_sum[i]

                });
```